# Ebean request giving 2 identic rows

Tags: postgresql, ebean, playframework-2.2

I have one row in my PostgreSQL table with the name I look for, but Ebean query gives me two identic results (same primary key). Each row has a unique name so I must be able to findUnique()

```
finder.where().eq("name", name).findUnique()
```

Handmade sql query gives me only one

```
String sql = "select id, name from totem where name ilike :name";
```

Any idea to get findUnique() working ?
Is it an Ebean bug ?

Comment: What do you see when you get the raw SQL that ebean executed from the PostgreSQL server error logs? Set `log_statement = 'all'`, reload PostgreSQL, run your test, and see what the server logs show. I suspect the ORM is generating a different query to what you think it is. Also: Are you really sure the name is unique? Is there an actual `UNIQUE` constraint on it in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a **OnetoOne** relationship with table B.

So Ebean generates an **inner join** with this table.

Table B has two entry corresponding the object I'm fetching on table A.

So the request returns **2 rows**.